# Optimizing nested loops in OR-Tools CP-SAT

Tags: c++, or-tools, cp-sat

We use OR-Tools to generate a task schedule for agents, at first in Python, now in C++.

Our code produces the desired result, but we're encountering a performance issue. The goal is to maximize the number of tasks shared between 2 agents (on tasks defined with a number of agents set to 2). The algorithm operates by minimizing the number of different agents each agent works with, which is more efficient than maximizing the number of shared tasks with each agent.

```cpp
std::vector<BoolVar> shared_sums;
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, BoolVar> shared;

for (int a1 = 0; a1 < num_agents; ++a1)
{
  for (int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < num_agents; ++a2)
  {
    for (int t = 0; t < num_tasks; ++t)
    {
      // ... code here to continue if task done by one agent

      cp_model.AddEquality(shared[{a1, a2}], 1)
      .WithName(absl::StrFormat("ct_eq_shared_%d_%d_%d", a1, a2, t))
          .OnlyEnforceIf({agent_task[a2][t], agent_task[a1][t]}); // agent_task[a1][t] BoolVar
    }
    shared_sums.push_back(shared[{a1, a2}]);
  }
}

cp_model.AddEquality(total_shared_sum, LinearExpr::Sum(shared_sums)).WithName("ct_eq_total_shared_sum");
cp_model.Minimize(total_shared_sum);
```

My issue is that for 100 agents and 100 tasks, my AddEquality constraint will be applied C(100,2) * 100 times, which is catastrophic in terms of performance.

What solution could I implement to optimize this constraint?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How many tasks can a agent do ?

Comment: I also have rules for that. An agent can have a limit (medical reasons), but he can have more than 50 tasks assigned because we have agents working 8 hours and tasks usually have a duration between 10mn and 90mn. Thanks

Comment: does the duration of the task depend on the number of agents assigned to it ?

Comment: Each task is defined with a duration and number of agents. For instance, if my task has a duration of 14 minutes, it will take 14 minutes if designated for 1 agent, and 2 * 14 minutes if designated for 2 agents.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a flow model:
1 boolvar `assign` for each (agent, task)
1 capacity for each agent
1 count var per task with domain [1, 2]

```
  for all agent: sum(assign(agent, task) * duration(task) for all task) <= capacity(agent))
  for all task: sum(assign(agent, task) for all agent) == count(task))
```

then the objective is just:

```
  minimize(sum(count(task) for all tasks - num_tasks))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how this algorithm will handle my pair preferences?
For example, with 5 agents, each working 4 hours, and 4 tasks requiring 2 agents for 2 hours + 1 task needing 1 agent for 2 hours, a result like this is good for us:

Agent A: T1 / T3
Agent B: T1 / T3
Agent C: T5*
Agent D: T2 / T4
Agent E: T2 / T4

This is what my algorithm crudely accomplishes. In this scenario, the total_shared_sum will be lower, making it better than if Agent A shares T1 with one agent and T2 with another.

Comment: this was not part of your original model. You just maximize the number of shared tasks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it would be simpler to just explain the problematic performance aspect, as the other constraints (limited time per agent, task limits per agent, prohibited tasks per agent, priority agents...) are easier to model and generate an optimal solution easily.